# GWT app not uploading on app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I am trying to upload simple web app created using GWT eclipse plugin to google app engine. 
I have created and tried with three ids but I can't deploy on the contrary it throws an error that

"`This application does not exist`"

```
ERROR:
Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=lathik6&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'lathik6').
```

I am using eclipse3.6 and jdk1.6 in windows7.

Comment: have you created the application lathik6. http://lathik6.appspot.com gives not found

Comment: Can be a problem with creation of application but I can login to my app engine account and it shows two application created I have tried to deploy  with both ids with same result.

Comment: I see that none of my id is working. Is the free scheme of google app engine still active or there is some change please kindly inform me if anyone knows..

Comment: Its still working.I was able to successfully deploy many apps.There is a limit of 10 apps though.Don't know whats the problem in ur case

Comment: vishes i have mailed you something

Comment: that did n't help.can't figure out ur problem.May be there is some problem wid ur eclipse plugin.are u using proxy ??you also need to verify your account by phone number before creating application.HTH

Comment: My eclipse plugin is alright and id is verified with my phone number as well.I just tested the app with an id created 5 months ago and its deplyoed   http://devcatalog.appspot.com/   thats why I am saying google may have changed the policy did you try my app id to deploy any of your app... Sorry if i am bothering you this is my last comment..

Comment: Finally my problem was solved when I downloaded the lated GWT AND APPENGINE SDK and used it deploy my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the App engine support in your gwt application . . ?? if not then add the support.